# How to replace network adapter?

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

This question is **NOT** about unplugging a broken NIC and plugging in a new one!  This is about the trauma experienced by the system (and sysadmin) caused by the new adapter's **NEW** device name.  For example, I have a machine running OpenVPN and Shorewall to provide remote access to our office's internal network.  The network card that connected to the outside internet failed and was replaced.  That's all well and good, and quite easy to do.

However...

The original device name was `enp5s4` and the replacement is being called `enp4s0`.  Unfortunately, this type of name is scattered throughout various configuration files and is a rather major problem to correct.  I found out that it is possible to *rename* a device (I found [instructions elsewhere](https://www.tomvanbrienen.nl/how-to-rename-ubuntu-18-04-an-network-ethernet-interface/)) and they *mostly* work.

I say *mostly* because, for some reason, netplan is never assigning the configuration for enp5s4 to the device, so it is just an ethernet card with no real purpose.

I'm at a loss for correcting this.  I can follow instructions well, but I am far from an expert and only just managed to cobble the OpenVPN server together last spring so we could work from home.  Can (will) anyone office help, ideas, hints or anything that may be useful?  Please?

**EDIT1**: The new card is in the same slot as the old card (the only slot available, in fact) but it is from a different manufacturer:  A Network Anywhere card replaced an old, broken D-Link card.  Now the system has TWO Network Anywhere cards (the original, `enp5s5` is still working perfectly.)

**EDIT2**: I tried telling my netplan to match the new adapter by `macaddress:`, and having the netplan set the name (and undid the changes from that link I found).  Now the system boots with the new NIC having the correct address and other settings, but I can only see other internet machines on my subnet (i.e. on our side of the 6 port cable modem my office has for internet service.)  That's really strange because all of the other computers on that subnet see the internet just fine through the cable modem.

**EDIT3**: Although the external internet link wasn't passing data, I left the system powered on last night (in case I was inspired to try something new.)  This morning I discovered it had crashed.  After rebooting (power off/on) it started logging `Internal fault: The skbuff addresses do not match in tulip_rx` messages over an over, one every few seconds.  So far I have only found the message in source repos and one 20-year-old thread about the error and playing *Quake*.  Note that despite these messages, I can still use both network cards to ping other computers on the subnets.  Any ideas while I try to get the cable company to check the modem?  Could these messages eventually have caused the system to crash or do I have something worse to investigate?

**EDIT4**:  The `skbuff` messages stopped after about nine minutes, and the *tulip* network adapter seems to have been working find the entire time and continues to do so.  The tulip NIC is NOT the one I replaced, so not sure why this started to happen now.  Still cannot see the external internet and waiting on the cable company for support.

Comment: Is the new card inserted in the *exact* same slot as the old one?

Comment: Stupid question, have you read `man netplan`? Also look here: https://netplan.io/examples/ PS `enp5s5` is actually a given name by netplan. You could name your network interfaces even `mickymouse` or `donaldduck`. Your old ethernet cards name is probably still reserved, find that file and adjust the MAC-address.

Comment: If after making the change in netplan you are able to access local network, but aren't able to access the Internet via cable modem, maybe the modem has MAC address filtering configured and rejects communication attempts from your new NIC, as it has a different MAC from the old one? You must consult the person who configured that modem.